# Trouble integrating google authentication into my PWA when running as an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, oauth, google-oauth, progressive-web-apps

I have a web application that is using the Google API for OAuth

I am working to get this ready to publish as a PWA into the Apple Store.

I am running into issues with the authentication.

I used PWABuilder to generate a package for iOS.  I downloaded the package and followed the instructions to create the Xcode project.

When testing with either the iPhone simulator integrated with Xcode or by using TestFlight to distribute the app, I an not able to authenticate using OAuth.

Initially I didn't have accounts.google.com added to the WKAppBoundDomains key in my Info file, without this it would not launch the authentication screens at all.

After I added that the OAuth screens would display, I am able to enter my google credentails (I even get the 2 factor authenticationr requests on my phone), but now it is hanging on a google screen with a spinning circle with the message "One Moment Please".

I could really use some advice on how to troubleshoot this (I not very familiar with XCode, or apple development in general), or a tried and true methods for including OAuth on PWA's that are published in the Apple store.

Thanks

Comment: In case anyone else is looking for an answer to this, this post on the PWABuilder's git hub page helped me resolve this: https://github.com/pwa-builder/PWABuilder/issues/2433